# Can an associatedtype have a type annotation?

Tags: swift, associated-types, type-annotation

I'm following an example and the author uses a type annotation on an associatedType however Xcode is throwing the error "cannont find type * in scope".  There aren't any Cocoapods or thirdparty frameworks being used.  Also I have tried to build the project but it doesn't compile.

Here is the type which is in a separate Swift file:

```
  import Foundation

protocol EndPointType {
    var baseURL: URL {get}
    var path: String {get}
    var httpMethod: HTTPMethod {get}
    var task: HTTPTask {get}
    var headers: HTTPHeaders? {get}
}
```

And this is the code from another Swift file which has the associatedType attempting to use a type annotation:

```
    import Foundation

public typealias NetworkRouterCompletion = (_ data: Data?,_ _response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?)->()

protocol NetworkRouter: class {
    associatedtype EndPoint: EndPointType
    func request(_ route: EndPoint, completion: @escaping NetworkRouterCompletion)
    func cancel()
}
```

Why wouldn't the second Swift file see the data type in order to compile?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Swift file into a subgroup and Xcode thought I deleted the file but it was in the workspace.  I moved the Swift file back into the subgroup and the problem went away.